# Access ActiveX objects in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a situtaion where i need the command prompt to open on the click of a button.  for this i started of by usign jsp.

> ```
> var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
> command = "cmd /k D:\ & cd testTrial & trial.bat & echo DONE!"
> wsh.Run(command);
> ```

The problem is that this wont run in firefox as ActiveXObject is a Microsoft propritory.
Is there a way i can check the browser and then run the above code  keeping the current browser in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a security hole... I don't think you will be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As I know for security reason other browsers does not allow to access local resources.

Comment: Is there any ohter way i can open a command prompt on button click?

Comment: If the end-users are in the same network with your web server, you can execute any batch or application remotely (of course you need an account with privilege to do so.